# What is usevshostingprocess in *.csproj?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csproj

Today, all of a sudden I found this in my *.csproj file

```
< UseVSHostingProcess> False </UseVSHostingProcess>
```

When i Compared it with latest it was added into

```
<PropertyGroup> </ Property Group>
```

I have alot search on Google and found
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171262.aspx, which I do not quite understand.

Can someone please explain what UseVSHostingProcess is and why it is needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the Visual Studio Hosting Process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069940/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-visual-studio-hosting-process)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069940/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-visual-studio-hosting-process

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I got this setting in my csproj file while using .NET Reflector Pro in Visual Studio to generate PDBs for 3rd party DLLs and debug them.

> The Visual Studio hosting process improves debugger performance and
>   enables new debugger features, such as partial-trust debugging and
>   design-time expression evaluation. You can disable the hosting process
>   if you need to.

Here is more information about this host process and debugging: [Debugging and the Hosting Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms242202.aspx)

Comment: In my case I have done nothing at all to my projects or VS2015 configuration, and suddenly these entries have appeared. At least, nothing I can think of. Every project in the solution seems to now have this.