# Unamanged DLL speed varies when whole solution is loaded

Tags: c#, c++, performance, unmanaged

I'm calling an unamaged 32bit-C++ library from a 64bit C# project. To test my methods and the functions of the library I created a rather simple wpf project. Using the test projects the library calls are handled pretty fast, so everything is fine.

My test-project is part of a bigger solution. When I run the whole solution, all the calls to the library get really slow (about 10 times slower).

I already unchecked "Enable unamanged code debuggin" and disabled the loading of the symbols without any improvements.

What else could I check to find the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figuered out what was slowing it down: while my project had the **Visual Studio Hosting Process** enabled, the solution startup project had it disabled.

After disabling it in my project, all calls to the dll were slowed down too, so I enabled it in the solution - and the calls are as fast as they should be now.

But, even after doing some research (e.g. here: [What is the purpose of the Visual Studio Hosting Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069940/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-visual-studio-hosting-process) or here [MSDN: Debugging and the Hosting Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242202.aspx)
) I'm not really any wiser why the "Visual Studio Hosting Process" is speeding the external calls up like this or why it could have been disabled in the first place.