# Console output not shown in Visual Studio when using Debugger.Launch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I'm attempting to debug a C#.NET application by means of System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() (or equivalently, by using VS to attach to an existing process).  For reasons I will not get into, I need to invoke the application from Windows Explorer rather than from within Visual Studio.

While almost everything works fine, I've found that the VS Output pane doesn't display any console messages when the debugger is attached in this way (i.e. Console.WriteLine(), printf() in pinvoke'd unmanaged DLLs, etc).  If I launch the debug session from within Visual Studio, all console messages appear in the Output pane, as expected.

So the question is: how can I attach the VS debugger to an existing process, but still be able to see console output in the VS output pane?

Edit: I have tried checking "Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window" in the VS options; it made no difference.

Comment: What about using Debug.WriteLine instead of Console.WriteLine?
Is it an option ? That may do it.

Comment: Interesting - that actually did work.  However, it unfortunately doesn't solve the problem in my case as I'm most interested in seeing printf() messages in unmanaged DLLs that I'm calling into.  Also, the existing C# codebase is huge and already has quite a few Console.WriteLine()-style messages peppered throughout...

Comment: Are you debugging a desktop application or anything else (ASP.NET, .. ) ?

Comment: Windows desktop application (C# and C++)

Comment: Please have a look at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3561f125-82d1-4374-9006-973277a31805/consolewritelineasd-does-not-write-to-output-window?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Read through them all; interesting log-related issues, but none seem to pertain to this situation (different behavior between initiating a debug session from within VS, vs launching the executable & then attaching the debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set the "Console.Out" stream to a FileStream, and output the content to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but as mentioned in my reply to your comment above, that doesn't really solve the problem in my case as I'm most interested in seeing printf (stdout & stderr) messages coming from unmanaged DLLs that I'm calling into.

Comment: (I realize I could redirect stdout & stderr to a file too, though these types of solutions are starting to get pretty roundabout, & checking a file is a far more cumbersome way to debug.  I'd much rather solve the "root issue" and figure out why *nothing* is appearing in the output pane, than to bandaid each stream I specifically know exists & deal with manually redirecting each to a file - which is for some reason only necessary if I attach the debugger to an existing process...)