# Console output ("Output Window") in Visual Studio 2013 not working any more?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a really peculiar and annoying issue with a WinForms (VB) solution: for no apparent reason the console output doesn't appear anymore. It works in other solutions, but not in this specific one.

I did indeed install Telerik's JustCode and JustTrace. Then I played arouund with the new features, did some coding when I sometime later noticed that the debug output from my application (using `Console.Writeline`) wasn't coming anymore. Build messages appear as do some VS messages, but not mine.

- I made sure I was checking the correct tab in the Output window.
- I restarted Visual Studio.
- I did a full reboot.
- I checked every option I could find, esp. Tools>Options>Debugging>Output Window and the options of the two Telerik tools) and everything was fine (and unchanged).
- I uninstalled the tools.
- I deleted the solution's .suo-file.
- I compared the .sln and .vbproj files to copies in our repository: no changes (in the relevant time frame).

Edits:

- I had the opportunity of running the solution on another computer; strangely with the same issues. That leads me to think it's got something to do with the .sln/.vbproj files.
- I redirected `Console.Out` to a `FileStream` and the output was written into the file as expected.
- I tried using `Console.OpenStandardOutput`, but without success.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. It's driving me crazy ...and it's only been a couple of hours...

Answer (score 0):

The painfully simple solution: check "Enable Visual Studio hosting process". Somehow I must've tripped over the checkbox and apparently longer ago than I had remembered which explains why I at first didn't find the difference in the .vbbproj file.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069940/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-visual-studio-hosting-process) SO question the information is also hidden.

Comment: Gosh - apparently no one else ever has these issues... Despite me just noticing that the debug output fails to appear (sometimes) without touching the option named above. A Visual Studio restart helps in that case. Maybe it's the switching between x86/x64? Maybe the tools (I re-installed)?

Comment: Just in case someone else does happen to have the same issue: as far as I could determine (through observation while working, not real testing) the "Enable Visual Studio hosting process" option appears to uncheck itself ...sometimes!?! So, if the console isn't working anymore, check that option for all related projects.